# PHP loop to sort table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm querying a database for names that are numbered 1-26 alphabetically. I have the following code, but since HTML is structured tr then td, the table appears alphabetically by row as opposed to by column. How can I make it appear in order by column?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM people WHERE main=1 ORDER BY id");
$i = 0;
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $name = $result['name'];
    if ($i % 5 == 0) echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td width=\"150\">";
    echo "<a href=\"#".strtolower($name)."\">".$name."</a><br />";
    echo "</td>\n";
    $i++;
    if ($i % 5 == 0) echo "</tr>\n";
};
```

alpha beta charlie
delta echo foxtrot

vs.

alpha charlie echo
beta delta foxtrot

Also, I'm open to reworking the code if there's a more efficient way.

Comment: what u want?? i really didn't got it till now?? which one is your desired output??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

After the discussion in the comments between myself, [Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) and the OP [bswinnerton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326111/bswinnerton), the following code seems to be the most effective:

```
$columns = 3;
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($query);
$rows = ceil($rowcount / $columns);
$rowdata = array_fill(0, $rows, "");
$ctr = 0;
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    $rowdata[$ctr++ % $rows] .= '<td>'.$result['name'].'</td>';
echo '<tr>'.implode('</tr><tr>',$rowdata).'</tr>';
```

This will create three *columns*, filled vertically (my original answer would create three *rows*). It also properly initializes the array (preventing PHP warnings), yields a correct row count for result counts that aren't divisible by the column count, and incorporates Kerrek's clever "calc-row-in-the-subscript" trick.

**Original Post:**

You could use arrays and implode() This way, you only have to make one pass through your results:

```
$row = 0;
$rows = 3;
$rowdata = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   if ($row >= $rows) $row = 0;
   $rowdata[$row++] .= '<td>'.$result['name'].'</td>';
}

echo '<tr>'.implode('</tr><tr>',$rowdata).'</tr>';
```

Comment: Cool. Even easier: `$rows[$i % $columns] .= "<td>$result['name']</td>";` Your `$col ` is never needed. But keep a counter `$i` around.

Comment: @Kerrek: The $col could be used to do something with the output, like assigning a class to the `td` or something. Removed for clarity of the solution. Also, I assume you meant `$rows[$row++ % $columns]`?

Comment: No sorry, I meant `$i % $columns`. No `$row`, just a continuous counter `$i`. I think your array `$rows` should really be called `$cols`, though!

Comment: Answer updated with a version based on your suggestion. I never thought to do the math inside the array subscript before. Clever! Also, I called it $rows because that's what it is, an array of `tr` contents (as evidenced by wrapping them with `<tr></tr>` at the end).

Comment: Hmm... hang on, does this really do the right thing? Somehow I don't think you can get away _whithout_ the full result count, non?

Comment: That's it - you should have `$r = NUMBER_OF_RESULTS / $columns$, and then say `$ctr++ % $r` -- otherwise it's the wrong way round!

Comment: Right, this gives you three rows instead of three columns... working on updated code... just a sec. _[sounds of wrenching]_

Comment: Youn can paste mine from above, I'll delete mine if you do.

Comment: @Justin, when setting $columns to 5, it displays 6 columns

Comment: and interestingly when setting $columns to 4, it displays 4. That must have something to do with $rows = $rowcount / $columns, no? Currently $rowcount is equal to 26

Comment: Yes, and I just saw that Kerrek's edited answer above has the resolution for that problem. I've updated my answer as well so as not to cause confusion. Add the extra bit to the `$rows =` line and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ah ha! That makes sense, I missed that as well. I know this is a rather novice subquestion, but with PHP error reporting, I'm getting an undefined offset error because the array isn't defined in the beginning. How can that be resolved?

Comment: You can just add a `for ($i = 0; $i <= $rows; $i++) $rowdata[$i] = '';` before the loop and after calculating the rows and it should initialize the array.

Comment: Also note that the current `$rows` computation fills up the columns greedily and leaves the last column very empty. E.g. 10 results, 3 cols would currently fill 4-4-2. If you rather want 4-3-3, we have to add some more code.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, actually I think I like 4-4-2. This is a table that will be used for navigation, so we would want it to look like a traditional table filling columns before rows.

Comment: @Justin: How about `array_fill(0, $rows, "");`?

Comment: You could probably have said something crazy like `$nrows = ($nresults - 0.1) / $ncols + 1;` to get the correct row count, but the integral type within me shudders at that. Wait. Even better: `$ceil($nresults / $ncols)`. D'oh.

Comment: You know, I just noticed that it's placing an extra empty <tr></tr> at the end. What could be the cause of that?

Comment: I know what's adding it.. the for loop: for ($i = 0; $i <= $rows; $i++) $rowdata[$i] = '';

Changed it to: for ($i = 0; $i <= $rows-1; $i++) $rowdata[$i] = '';

Answer (score 5):

You could just access the output array in strides. Compute how many rows you need as the number of results divided by 5, and use the row count as the stride.

```
$ncols = 5;
$nrows = $nresults / $ncols + ($nresults % $ncols == 0 ? 0 : 1);

for ($i = 0; $i < $nrows; $i++)
{
   // start row
   for ($j = 0; $k < $ncols; $j++)
   {
     // print $results[$nrows * $j + $i]
   }
   // end row
}
```

You'll have to transfer your query results into an array `$results` first. Since you'll have to know the total number of results, this is sort of mandatory, though I'd be curious if anyone has a solution that can work while fetching the results.

*Update:* See Justin's answer for a cool solution that grows the output while fetching the query results line by line. Since it's currently being worked on, here's a summary (credits to Justin):

```
$nresults = mysql_num_rows($query);
$ncols = 5;
$nrows = (int) ceil($nresults / $ncols);

$i = 0; $cols = array_fill(0, $nrows, "");

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  $cols[$i++ % $nrows] .= "<td>$result['name']</td>";

echo "<tr>" . implode("</tr><tr>", $cols) . "</tr>";
```